# How to disable Django showing decimal separator in templates?

Tags: python, django, decimalformat

I have a Django app, when i was writing the code on my pc, it was showing the numbers in the templates in this style:

```
1000 -> 1,000 (I use the use thousand separator)
```

But when i deployed the app to my server, it shows:

```
1000 -> 1,000.00
```

but i don't what to use the numbers with the decimal separator. I tried formatting the numbers with the intcoma filter but doesn't work anyway. 
How i can get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the floatformat filter from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the floatformat:"0" filter works!. I'm already thinking why i missed that in the docs :)

Answer (score 0):

This probably has something to do with your Django locale settings and your browser locale settings.

I would recommend checking for possible differences in your development and production `settings.py`, specifically looking for:

- [THOUSAND_SEPARATOR](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#use-thousand-separator)
- [DECIMAL_SEPARATOR](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#decimal-separator)
- [USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#use-thousand-separator)

Comment: I've already checked those options, but it makes no differences. 
Well, in general, if i don't use any separator, the numbers appear like this. 
1000 -> 1000.00. I don't know the reason of this. And in development environment, the numbers appears without the Decimal. I will add as a plus that i'm using postgres as database.